# How to get specific places category in Google Maps Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to retrieve information from this kind of Google information card

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEabR.png)

Through Google Places API, I manage to get nearly every piece of information you see here. The last thing I am missing is the precise category just beneath the place name ie "Corporate Office" in my example.

The API returns a rough category (establishement) but not this very precise (and precious) information.

Is there any other API to get it ?
I tried Google forums without success.

Any trick about how to get it ?
(not at an industrial scale)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue right now and the only thing the API returns is an array for the field "type" (point_of_interest, establishment), but not the specific one which is listed on Google Maps, like "Corporate Office" in your example.